# Dart optional vlaue as prop

Tags: flutter, dart, optional-parameters

I am new to Flutter/Dart but I have experience with Typescript. Can you help me with the following code and question:

```dart
final String? title;

appBar: title != null
        ? AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
          )
        : null,
```

I am getting the error message `The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'`.

I thought that the condition `title != null` would ensure that `title` is not null. Is there a better way to handle this? to not add just `Text(title!),`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only local variables can be used like that because there are situations where the `title` can return `null` the second time it's accessed. So you could do this if you really don't want to use `!`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final t = title;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: t != null
            ? AppBar(
          title: Text(t),
        )
            : null,
```

To give an example of why it's not guaranteed that `title` is not null the second time consider this program:

```
import 'dart:math';

main() {
  var b = B('whatever');
  b.printTitleLength();
}

class A {
  final String? title;

  A(this.title);

  void printTitleLength() {
    if (title != null) {
      print(title!.length);
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
  B(super.title);

  @override
  String? get title => Random().nextBool() ? 'test' : null;
}
```

Note I had to put the `!` in the print line otherwise it wouldn't compile. But also note that this possibly can throw an exception since it's possible `title` returns null after the null check.

Comment: @savkevip I also added an example of why it could go wrong with non-local variables

Comment: For a video of that, check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqS_Q34RcUk

Comment: @RandalSchwartz i think it was actually your video that I learned it from long time ago. I forgot about it. And your answer is really nice with the new patterns in dart. I still need to get used to the new features

Answer (score 1):

use null aware operator to assign a default value when title is null, as Text widget expects a non null value.

```
final String? title;

appBar: title != null
        ? AppBar(
            title: Text(title??""),
          )
        : null,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch expression to solve this now:

```
appbar: switch(title) { String t => AppBar(title: t), _ => null },
```

This works because title is copied into a new t variable, and guaranteed to be non-null.  If it's null, it falls through to the catch-all.

Answer (score 0):

Dart is null-safe,

so you can't define a variable without giving it an init value,

you may define an init value and it will be an empty string or if you are sure that you will give value to that variable before assigning it to the screen you can use **late** keyword, **Note** that if you misuse it and didn't assign a value before the screen is built, you will get a null error in the screen.

if you want it to accept that **title** could be a string or null you put the **?** after **String**.

if you want to use that variable you need to put **The null assertion operator (!)**
telling dart that you are sure it won't be null during runtime

refer to this documentation to have a better understanding of Null Safety in Dart [Null Safety](https://dart.cn/codelabs/null-safety)